# remove or replace mobile player's play button video.js

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, video

I am using [**video.js**](http://www.videojs.com/)

Have intro landing page which starts with fullwidth, fullheight video as background. On mobiles such as Iphone when you click on play button it plays with player on mobile, not as background video. And when I pause video from that player it adds its personal play button and mine isn't visible at all.

[image: Player's play button]

Want to know is there any way to remove it or replace?

Comment: There seems to be a `controls` option in the API (https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/api/vjs.Player.md#controls-controls-). Have you tried using that?

Comment: yes I tried, but no success @Ozan